# Many ProducerS and many ConsumerS. Making the last producer alive killing the consumers

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have a standard producer consumer problem. Producer puts data into the stack(buffer) consumers take it.

I would like to have many producers and consumers.

**the problem is I would like to make only the last living producer to be able to call `b.stop()`**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        try{
    //      sleep((int)(Math.random() * 1));                
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        b.put((int) (Math.random()* 10));
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
    b.stop();
```

so then I call `b.stop()` which changes `running` field in `Buffer` to false and `notifiesAll()`

End then I get:

```
i = 9 // number of iteration this is 10th iteration
Consumer 2.: no data to take. I wait.  Memory: 0
Consumer 1.: no data to take. I wait.  Memory: 0
Consumer 3.: no data to take. I wait.  Memory: 0
```

they should die then, so I made method stop() but it did not work.

Code is running please check it

```
import java.util.Stack;


public class Buffer {
private static int SIZE = 4;
private int i;//number of elements in buffer
public Stack<Integer> stack;
private volatile boolean running;
    public Buffer() {
        stack = new Stack<>();
        running = true;
        i = 0;
    }
    synchronized public void put(int val){
        while (i >= SIZE) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Buffer full, producer waits");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        stack.push(val);//txt = s;
        i++;
        System.out.println("Producer inserted " + val + " memory: " + i);
        if(i - 1 == 0)
            notifyAll();
        System.out.println(stack);
    }

    public synchronized Integer get(Consumer c) {
        while (i == 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println(c + ": no data to take. I wait.  Memory: " + i);
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        if(running){
            int data = stack.pop();
            i--;    
            System.out.println(c+  ": I took: " + data +" memory: " +  i);
            System.out.println(stack);
            if(i + 1 == SIZE){//if the buffer was full so the producer is waiting
                notifyAll();
                System.out.println(c +  "I notified producer about it");
        }
        return data;}
        else 
            return null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return i == 0;
    }
    public synchronized void stop(){//I THOUGH THIS WOULD FIX IT~!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        running = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
    public boolean isRunning(){
        return running;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
private Buffer b;
    public Producer(Buffer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            try{
        //      sleep((int)(Math.random() * 1));                
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            b.put((int) (Math.random()* 10));
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
        }
        b.stop();
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {
    Buffer b;
    int nr;
    static int NR = 0;

    public Consumer(Buffer b) {
        this.b = b;
        nr = ++NR;
    }

    public void run() {
        Integer i = b.get(this);
        while (i != null) {
            System.out.println(nr + " I received : " + i);
            i = b.get(this);
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer " + nr + " is dead");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Consumer " + nr + ".";
}

}
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Buffer b = new Buffer();
        Producer p = new Producer(b);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(b);
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer(b);
        Consumer c3 = new Consumer(b);  
        p.start();
        c1.start();c2.start();c3.start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to realise is that your threads could be waiting in either of two locations:

1. In the `wait` loop with `i == 0` - in which case `notifyall` will kick all of them out. However, if `i` is still `0` they will go straight back to waiting again.
2. Waiting for exclusive access to the object (i.e. waiting on a `synchronized` method) - in which case (if you fix issue 1 above and the lock will be released) they will go straight into a `while (i == 0)` loop.

I would suggest you change your `while ( i == 0 )` loop to `while ( running && i == 0 )`. This **should** fix your problem. Since your `running` flag is (correctly) `volatile` all should tidily exit.

Comment: I forgot to change it in the post.. I have `while ( running && i == 0 )` but the problem is I would like to make only the last living producer to be able to call `b.stop()`

Answer (score 0):

In your `stop` method, you set `running` to `false`, but your while loop is running as long as `i == 0`. Set `i` to something different than zero and it should fix it.

BTW, I don't understand why you have a `running` variable and a separate `i` variable, which is actually the variable keeping a thread running.

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink your design. Classes should have a coherent set of responsibilities; making a class responsible for both consuming objects off the queue, while also being responsible for shutting down other consumers, seems to be something you'd want to seperate.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the **to make only the last living producer to be able to call b.stop()**.

You should add an `AtomicInteger` to your `Buffer` containing the number of producers and make each producer call `b.start()` (which increments it) in its constructor.

That way you can decrement it in `b.stop()` and only when it has gone to zero should `running` be set to `false`.